# nm и статическая библиотека

Tags: c++

Возник такой вопрос: как `nm` работает со статическими библиотеками? Всмысле так же как и с динамическими или есть какие-то особенности? Возникла проблема с `undefined reference to vtable` которую я пофиксил с помощью `nm`, но тут увидел, что для статичекой библиотеки все еще показывает `U vtable` для классов, методы которых должны быть в этой библиотеке. При этом для динамической библиотеки все найдено. Также если мы линкуем статическую библиотеку к нашей программе, то тоже все работает, хотя в `nm` показывает что некоторы классы - наследники от абстрактного базового класса - `U vtable for`... Почему так?

Comment: Вывод можно посмотреть?

Comment: @isnullxbh он огромен (более 3000 строк), так что записать весь сюда не получится